# Sympy calculation on tan function

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have a problem when simplifying a symbolic expression in sympy when having a trigonometric function and a complex exponent, namely I just assumed a different definition of tan function, and I have a weird thing going on. So I do:

```
# Deleting variables
from IPython import get_ipython;   
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')

import sympy as sym;

# defining variables
test1 = sym.Symbol('test');
test2 = sym.Symbol('test2');
a = sym.Symbol('a');

# Defining tests
test1 = sym.tan(a) + sym.I*(sym.exp(sym.I*a)-sym.exp(-sym.I*a))/(sym.exp(sym.I*a)+sym.exp(-sym.I*a));
test2 = sym.I*(sym.exp(sym.I*a)-sym.exp(-sym.I*a))/(sym.exp(sym.I*a)+sym.exp(-sym.I*a));
```

Symbolic variable sym.simplify(test2) is equal to -tan(a) and normaly test1 variable should be equal to 0, however when I simplify a test1 variable, I do get:

```
sym.simplify(test1)
Out[140]: 
(-I*(1 - exp(2*I*a)) + (exp(2*I*a) + 1)*tan(a))/(exp(2*I*a) + 1)
```

So the question is what do I get wrong, how to tell Python to simplify a text1 expression in order to get  0 which it naturally should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting in terms of `exp` then simplifying gives `0`

```py
test1.rewrite(sym.exp).simplify()
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, I see that this solution works well. I am new to sympy so could I ask you about the explanation what this command does? What does .rewrite(sym.exp) do? Is there a documentation or help that helps to understand?

Comment: checkout https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.rewrite